# How does row or table locking work in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

What is the Linq equivalent for row locking hints in SQL?  For example:

```
select *
  from MyTable with (updlock)
 where MyField like 'A%'
```

Or is the whole question moot, because Linq caches all the objects anyway and it can't handle concurrent updates to an object already residing in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work; Linq has no mechanism for this.  It'd be nice to have, but it's hard to provide locking hints in a database-independent way.  However, you can still use stored procedures or System.Transactions to achieve the same effect.